# Etcd disk size metric

Tags: prometheus, etcd

I need to monitor my etcd cluster and I would like to use the following prometheus metric to monitor my cluster:

```
etcd_mvcc_db_total_size_in_bytes
```

according to the documentation:

```
Total size of the underlying database physically allocated in bytes.
```

This metrics return something like 2048 bytes (2Kb).

Now I think people interested to monitor disk size are interested to monitor it in order to identify filesystem full issues. Now the problem is that in my installation the Etcd data directory `/run/etcd/default.etcd` contains the following folders with this size:

```
member/snap    -> 3.3 Mb
member/snap/db -> 2048 bytes
member/wal     -> 367 Mb
```

It's clear to me that the metric above measure the size of the file `member/snap/db` but this is not really useful for me (and I think also other people). People are more interested to the size of data directory and be notified (with Grafana alert) when this size reach a given limit.

Now I didn't find any metric that allow me to calculate the size of the whole Etcd data directory. **Does anyone know how to do that?**

Another question I have is the following. I use this Etcd cluster with Patroni (a cluster manager for automatic failover in PostgreSQL), it uses Etcd only to keep track who is the leader. I expect to have very few data in it. In fact, `member/snap/db`is very small. However, I don't understand the needs for folders `member/snap`for snapshots and `member/wal`for wal. It's not clear to me if it is a way to reduce the size of these folder.

Looking at many websites and documentation I noticed commands to reduce revision but regularly they don't work. I use Etcd 3.3.20 and later versions don't work with Patroni. This is the commands available in my version:

```
COMMANDS:
     backup          backup an etcd directory
     cluster-health  check the health of the etcd cluster
     mk              make a new key with a given value
     mkdir           make a new directory
     rm              remove a key or a directory
     rmdir           removes the key if it is an empty directory or a key-value pair
     get             retrieve the value of a key
     ls              retrieve a directory
     set             set the value of a key
     setdir          create a new directory or update an existing directory TTL
     update          update an existing key with a given value
     updatedir       update an existing directory
     watch           watch a key for changes
     exec-watch      watch a key for changes and exec an executable
     member          member add, remove and list subcommands
     user            user add, grant and revoke subcommands
     role            role add, grant and revoke subcommands
     auth            overall auth controls
     help, h         Shows a list of commands or help for one command
```

Comment: I second this question. ETCD DB SIZE is 25MB and yet 300+ on disk.